# How to get users from specific groups using wildcards with filters in AD?

Tags: active-directory, ldap-query

I'm trying to do a query as follow, using All Users Filter:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=GROUP_*,OU=Common Groups,OU=MYCOMPA,DC=mycompa,DC=com))
```

I know this cant be done, but I haven't found a way to do something similar. I have 3 groups, GROUP_A, GROUP_B and GROUP_C. I want to get the users from any of these 3 groups, so something with GROUP_* should do the filter.

I tried with:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(cn=GROUP_*))
```

But it returns nothing, since it has the DC defined. Any clue about this?. I'm not programming, just need the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not exist a single search filter to do this.

The proper way is to search for all groups you want. And then do a search for each of the groups. But this is programming. :)